# Find all common N-sized tuples in list of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, sqlite, numpy

I have to create an an application that does the following (I have to parse the data only once and store them in a database):

I am given K tuples (with K over 1000000) and each tuple is in the form of

```
(UUID, (tuple of N integers))
```

Lets assume that N equals 20 for every k-tuple and that every 20-sized tuple is sorted.
I have saved all my data in a database in the following two forms (2 different tables), so that I can process them more easily:

1. _id, UUID, tuple.as_a_string()
2. _id, UUID, 1st_elem, 2nd_elem, 3rd_3lem, ... 20th_elem

The goal is to find all 10-sized tuples from the list of tuples, such that every one of those tuples to exist in more than one 20-sized tuple.**

For example, if we are given the two following 20-sized tuples:

```
(1, (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,161,17,18,19,20))
(2, (1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39))
```

the common tuple is: (1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19)

which is a 10-sized tuple, so the result is something like the following:

```
(1, 2, (1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19))
```

In order to accomplish this, what I am currently doing is (in Python 3):

- Create a set with the elements of the 20-sized tuple of the 1st row in the database.
- Create a set for each row with the elements of the 20-sized tuple of the rest rows in the database.
- For each set in the second list of sets, I do the intersection with the first set.
- Then I create the combination of the intersection with 10 elements *(in Python it is itertools.combinations(new_set, 10) )*, which gives me the result that I want.

But this procedure is **very slow**. Even using multiprocessing to utilize my 8 CPU cores fully, each computing for a different number, it takes forever. I have the program running for 2 days now and it is only in 20%.

Do you have any ideas on how to optimize the process? Would NumPy arrays help with the speed of execution? Is there any way in SQL to calculate what I want for each row, even one row at a time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged SQL?  What is your data representation?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to tag only with SQLite. I miss clicked. My data are tuples of integers with size 20, each one with a unique ID assigned to the tuple.

Comment: if it is sqlite, shouldn't you be writing SQL to do this instead of python?

Comment: @TiMace . . . Do you want an answer in SQL or Python?  "tuple" is much more commonly used when talking about Python.  The concept exists in SQL, but is more commonly referred to as a "row".  However, how is the data being represented in SQLite?  Nested tuples are not supported.

Comment: @deltaskelta I am open in suggestions for any solutions, like some other form of saving my data in the db, or using a query to filter out data before processing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff any answer is wanted. I am aware that tuple is a term used more in functional programming languages and row in relational DBMS. I represent the data either as 20 different rows or as a string of comma separated integers.

Comment: @DanD. Yes encoding as bitsets is possible. But the intersection of two sets is already really fast and optimized and I believe it would make very little difference. But I will try it and report back.

Comment: How big are the integers in the tuples?

Comment: @BillBell They are between 1 and 99 inclusive. And there are no repetitions in any tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be much hope for this:  forgetting the `combinations()` part, you need to check the intersection of every pair of `K` tuples.  There are `choose(K, 2) = K*(K-1)/2` pairs, so with a million tuples there are nearly 500 billion pairs.

One low-level trick you can play is to represent a tuple as an integer instead of as a set, where bit `2**i` is set in the integer when and only when `i` is in the tuple.  Since you said in comments that a tuple contains no duplicates, and each tuple element is in `range(1, 100)`, 100-bit integers are sufficient (it could be cut to 99 bits, but not worth the bother).

The point is that bitwise "&" of integers goes a lot faster than set intersection.  On my box, about 7 times faster.  Here's some code to illustrate the concept, and some sloppy timing results (run on a machine doing lots of other stuff simultaneously):

```
def build(K, values, N):
    from random import sample
    sets = []
    ints = []
    for i in range(K):
        t = sample(values, N)
        sets.append(set(t))
        ints.append(sum(1 << i for i in t))
    return sets, ints

def run(K, values, N):
    from time import time
    as_sets, as_ints = build(K, values, N)
    for meth, collection in [("sets", as_sets),
                             ("ints", as_ints)]:
        s = time()
        for i in range(K-1):
            base = collection[i]
            for j in range(i+1, K):
                x = base & collection[j]
        t = time()
        print("K", K, meth, t-s)

for K in 5000, 10000, 20000:
    run(K, range(1, 100), 20)
```

And output:

```
K 5000 sets 7.322501182556152
K 5000 ints 1.0357279777526855
K 10000 sets 30.60071086883545
K 10000 ints 4.150524377822876
K 20000 sets 128.24610686302185
K 20000 ints 15.933331727981567
```

Note that, as expected, runtime for either approach is quadratic in K (so doubling K takes about 4 times as long; and making K 10 times larger would increase runtime by a factor of about 10**2 = 100).

While intersection is much faster with ints, determining the cardinality of the result is slower.  There are many ways to do that, but "the best" depends on the expected distribution and your tolerance for coding pain ;-)  Here's an overview of the [major methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight).

Comment: I chose to use bitsets, in a combination of what you recommended and what I already had done and I saw a 50x performance boost.
I used bitsets to represent my sets and just used the AND operator. 0 represents not existing number, while 1 existing. Simple and efficient.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you could put the tuples into the rows of a matrix and make a map from row numbers to UUIDs. Then it's feasible to store all of the tuples in a numpy array since the elements of the tuples are small. numpy has code capable of computing the intersections between rows of such an array. This code generates combinations to process as tuples first, then it makes the comparisons.

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
from time import time

minInt=1
maxInt=100
tupleSize=20
intersectionSize=10

K=100
rows=np.zeros((K,tupleSize),dtype=np.int8)
print ('rows uses', rows.nbytes, 'bytes')

for i,c in enumerate(combinations(range(minInt,maxInt),tupleSize)):
    if i>=K:
        break
    for j,_ in enumerate(c):
        rows[i,j]=_

t_begin=time()
for i in range(K-1):
    for j in range(i+1,K):
        intrsect=np.intersect1d(rows[i],rows[j],True)
        if intrsect.shape[0]==intersectionSize:
            print (i,j,intrsect)
t_finish=time()

print ('K=', K, t_finish-t_begin, 'seconds')
```

Here are some sample measurements made on my old two-core P4 clunker at home.

rows uses 200 bytes
K= 10 0.0009770393371582031 seconds

rows uses 1000 bytes
K= 50 0.0410161018371582 seconds

rows uses 2000 bytes
K= 100 0.15625 seconds

rows uses 10000 bytes
K= 500 3.610351085662842 seconds

rows uses 20000 bytes
K= 1000 14.931640863418579 seconds

rows uses 100000 bytes
K= 5000 379.5498049259186 seconds

If you run the code on your machine you can extrapolate. I don't know if it would make your calculation feasible or not.

Maybe I'll just get a bunch of negative votes!

Comment: This solution is not an improvement on what I am trying to achieve, because the fact that the dataset is so huge, is what makes my life difficult. However, the organization in numpy arrays, actually gave me some performance improvement, because of access times, not a big boost though.
Thank you for your input!

Comment: You're most welcome. I thought that, at the very least, it might answer one or two questions and prompt others to comment, which it did.

Answer (score 2):

Bill, I think this creates a more random mix.  Your combinations version steps systematically through the choices.  With small K the intersection size is close to `tupleSize`.

```
choices = np.arange(minInt, maxInt)
for i in range(K):
    rows[i,:] = np.random.choice(choices, tupleSize, replace=False)
```

Using `sets` is about 4x faster than `np.intersect1d`.

```
sets = [set(row) for row in rows]
dd = collections.defaultdict(int)
for i in range(K-1):
    for j in range(i+1,K):
        intrsect=sets[i].intersection(sets[j])
        dd[len(intrsect)] += 1
```

I switched to collecting the intersection size, as it is more interesting and less sensitive to iteration strategy.

With K=5000:

```
K= 5000 221.06068444252014 seconds
{0: 77209, 1: 514568, 2: 1524564, 3: 2653485, 4: 3044429, 5: 2436717, 6: 1408293, 7: 596370, 8: 188707, 9: 44262, 10: 7783, 11: 1012, 12: 93, 13: 8}
```

The smaller time is just for the `sets` creation step; that's very fast.

```
K= 5000 0.058181047439575195 46.79403018951416 seconds
{0: 77209, 1: 514568, 2: 1524564, 3: 2653485, 4: 3044429, 5: 2436717, 6: 1408293, 7: 596370, 8: 188707, 9: 44262, 10: 7783, 11: 1012, 12: 93, 13: 8}
```

for larger K

```
K= 10000 818.3419544696808 seconds
{0: 309241, 1: 2058883, 2: 6096016, 3: 10625523, 4: 12184030, 5: 9749827, 6: 5620209, 7: 2386389, 8: 752233, 9: 176918, 10: 31168, 11: 4136, 12: 407, 13: 18, 14: 2}
K= 10000 0.09764814376831055 151.11484718322754 seconds
```

Comment: Paul, thanks for responding. It would be beneficial to many of us to have comparisons like this prominently displayed. But where?